# Metropolis Hastings Stuck in Local maxima

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings

I've been running the metropolis hastings algorithm to infer some parameters.

After running multiple chains, there are typically two places the chains get stuck in, one of which has a higher likelihood than the other. How can I stop this happening? The chains look like they've converged, and have spent >95% of the iterations in this location, but obviously there's a better location that a lot of the chains can't find. Is there a way I can 'perturb' the chains to reach this place? Or is it valid to update my prior to use this greater likelihood location as my new prior?

Parameters are in continuous space. I'm using and Adaptive metropolis algorithm, with a multivariate normal proposal. Normal or uniform priors. I wouldn't have thought I'd expect multimodality, but it is difficult to tell.

Comment: Your problem is too broadly specified - are you using random walk Metropolis-Hastings? Are you on a discrete or continuous space? Do you expect multimodality?

Comment: Apologies. Will add this to the question.

Parameters are in continuous space. Adaptive metropolis, but multivariate normal proposal. Normal or uniform priors. I wouldn't have thought I'd expect multimodality, but it is difficult to tell.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Would also be nice to have your posterior written out and the dimension of your state space.